# How to modify a Skobbler Annotation without re adding it

Tags: android, skmaps

I have to modify the image of a SKAnnotation.
Annotation builder code:

```
private SKAnnotation getAnnotationFromView (int id,int minZoomLvl, View view) {
    SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
    SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
    annotationView.setView(view);
    annotation.setUniqueID(id);
    annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(annotationView.getWidth()/2, annotationView.getHeight()/2));
    annotation.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
    annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(minZoomLvl);
    return annotation;
}
```

Now my problem is to update the annotation/image to the current state (position, orientation). Is there a way doing that without re adding the annotation? Looking into the documentation I found `mapView.updateAnnotation()` but it seems to work just for images added with `annotation.setImagePath(imagePath)`
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Even I am looking for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

There is an inconsistency in the implementation (we'll address that in a future update) that allows one to reposition only annotations with the icon taken from an file.

If you'd like to reposition an (any) annotation you could/should remove it and add it again.

If you'd like to change the icon/view - then the `updateAnnotation` API should do the job

Comment: Hi Ando, please find the below code snippet. updateAnnotation API is not changing on the map view.

Comment: @Charan - please ask another question and include the provided code snippet

Comment: Asked new question. Please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152601/update-annaotation-api-not-working