# Update Annotation API not working

Tags: android, skmaps

I am using update Annotation API in skobbler maps on Android for offline purpose. I change the annotation view and update the annotation via updateAnnotation API.

```
SKAnnotation currentAnnotation = mAnnotations.get(mSelectedIndex);
SKAnnotationView currentView = currentAnnotation.getAnnotationView();
currentView.setView(createDrawableFromView(TestActivity.this, true, "2500"));
currentAnnotation.setAnnotationView(currentView);
mSKMapView.updateAnnotation(currentAnnotation);
```

However, updateAnnotation is not working. Please let me know on this.

And, how to add and handle click event for custom annotations.

Comment: Did you you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781358/how-to-modify-a-skobbler-annotation-without-re-adding-it?lq=1?

Comment: Yes Ando, I checked. No luck with that code/idea. However, using updateAnnotation API, new view is not reflected for same Annotation.

Comment: Please add the code snippet for the initial annotation (how you create your initial annotation)

Comment: Hi Ando, code snippet for the initial annotation. Please check here: http://postimg.org/image/sdbwzej9z/

Comment: any update on this API??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating this it turns out that the updateAnnotation API was not implemented for custom views in the 2.3 SDK version.

We will have this in 2.4 SDK.

Comment: Okay. I ended up using default annotations, and updateAnnotation API works fine. However, for some annotations it fails. I need to debug and do more checks on this. Thanks for the info Ando.